# Are all norms equivalent on a (non-semisimple) commutative Banach algebra?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, banach-algebras

On a semisimple commutative Banach algebra all Banach algebra norms are equivalent. Is this true without assuming semisimplicity?

Comment: What about a vector space with inequivalent Banach space norms given the $0$ product?

Answer (score 0):

No.  E.g., $\ell^2$ and $\ell^\infty$ have the same dimension as vector spaces, so on a vector space of this dimension you can put inequivalent Banach space norms.  Give it the zero product.